# Httperf: How to test REST api with endoded uri

Tags: rest, httperf

I want to test my REST API which has a URI something like this:

```
/myrestAPI/search?startTime=0&endTime=10&count=8&filters={"params":
    [{"field":"Topic","value":"Algorithms","type":"MATCH_EXACT"}]}
```

How would I do that. The `httperf` reply status is "505 HTTP Version Not Supported"
I know that this uri the `httperf` is not properly encoding and sending it..

How would I achieve that in `httperf`?

Comment: Any Idea how to achieve above???

Comment: Does anybody have any idea about achieving that. I have spent like a week in doing all sorts o permutations and combinations... Help me

Answer (score 0):

Since URLs often contain characters outside the ASCII set, the URL has to be converted into a valid ASCII format.

URL encoding replaces unsafe ASCII characters with a "%" followed by two hexadecimal digits.

For you case, it would be:

```
/myrestAPI/search?startTime=0&endTime=10&count=8&filters=%7B%22params%22%3A%20%5B%7B%22field%22%3A%22Topic%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22Algorithms%22%2C%22type%22%3A%22MATCH_EXACT%22%7D%5D%7D
```

Try to experiment with [URL encoder/decoder](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/)